# Pythonic way to assure that a parameter is an instance of a class

Tags: python

Let's say that I have the following class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
    ...
```

And also this function:

```
def foo(my_class):
    ...
```

My question is: **what is the pythonic way to assure that `my_class` parameter is an instance of `MyClass()`?**

Comment: Python has no type checker, but you can (in Python-3.x) use type hints, and `assert`s.

Comment: Could you post a simple example with assertions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `isinstance` builtin:

```
isinstance(my_class, MyClass)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use `assert` along with `isinstance`:

```
assert isinstance(my_class, MyClass)
```

If `my_class` is not instance of `MyClass` an exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 3):

May be simple one is, [more help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)

```
isinstance(obj, MyClass)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be:

```
type(obj) is MyClass
```

But the **Pythonic way**, of course:

```
isinstance(my_class, MyClass)
```

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way of assuring is not checking at all. Let [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) do the job. Or you can use Python 3's type hints like said in the comments section. Otherwise, specifically check the type if you **really really** need to.